# Jest only runs single project when specifying two config.js

Tags: javascript, jestjs, package.json

I have two projects specified in the jest section of my `package.json`.

```
"jest": {
    "projects": ["<rootDir>/jest.unit.config.js", "<rootDir>/tests/jest.component.config.js"]
}
```

Whenever I run `jest` on the command line it only picks up and finds the `jest.component.config.js`.

I have tried removing `jest.component.config.js` from the projects list and running `jest` and it does successfully run the unit test config in that case.

What's the trick to it finding and running both?

```js
//jest.unit.config.js
const jestConfig = require('/common/jest.config');

module.exports = Object.assign(jestConfig, {
    displayName: {
        color: 'cyan',
        name: 'unit-tests'
    },
    coverageThreshold: {
        global: {
            branches: 20,
            functions: 20,
            lines: 20,
            statements: 20,
        }
    }
});
```

```js
//jest.component.config.js
const jestConfig = require('common/jest.config');

module.exports = Object.assign(jestConfig, {
    rootDir: '.',
    displayName: {
        color: 'yellow',
        name: 'component-tests',
    },
    testMatch: ['./**/*test.ts'],
    testEnvironment: './helpers/test-environment.js',
});
```

```js
//common jest.config.js

module.exports = {
    collectCoverage: true,
    collectCoverageFrom: [
        "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,mjs}",
    ],
    coverageDirectory: "<rootDir>/coverage",
    coverageProvider: 'babel',
    coverageReporters: ['text', 'html'],
    coverageThreshold: {
        global: {
            branches: 50,
            functions: 50,
            lines: 50,
            statements: 50,
        },
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'mjs', 'json'],
    modulePathIgnorePatterns: [],
    prettierPath: "prettier",
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    testMatch: ['**/__tests__/**/*.(js|ts|jsx|tsx|mjs)'],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/fixtures/', '/__tests__/helpers/', '__mocks__', 'dist', '.yalc'],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$': 'ts-jest',
        '^.+\\\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$': 'babel-jest',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|ts|jsx|tsx|mjs)$'],
};
```

Comment: Just a note that jest --config='path/to/jest/file' works, but I'd rather be able to run them both simultaneously if necessary. and I thought that's what the multi-project runner was for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was overwriting my common jest config with the `Object.assign(..)` and thus stopping whichever project was first in the list of projects.

To fix this, I was able to make a deep copy of it before using the assign instead.

```js
const commonJest = require('common/jest.config');

const commonJestCopy = Object.assign({}, commonJest)

module.exports = Object.assign(commonJestCopy, {
    //...overrides
}
```